# regexp last occurance of a pattern to end of string in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I have a string like

```
    AVPs_List,Vendor_Specific_Application_Id,3,AVP.Vendor_ID,0,AVP.Header,AVP.Code
```

I want to regexp / regsub to get a output like

```
    AVPs_List,Vendor_Specific_Application_Id,3,AVP.Vendor_ID
```

Actually I want to subtract the part from the last occurance of the pattern "***,[0-9],***" to the end of string. like for string < **xxxx,9898,yyyy,87,zzzz,56,aaaa** > , i want to get < **xxxx,9898,yyyy,87,zzzz** >

I am doing regexp based on the pattern ,[0-9], and using this code

```
    regsub {(,)([0-9]+)(,).*} $str1 "" $result
```

but string is trimmed from first occurance and looks like

```
    AVPs_List,Vendor_Specific_Application_Id
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match instead, like this:

```
% set str1 "AVPs_List,Vendor_Specific_Application_Id,3,AVP.Vendor_ID,0,AVP.Header,AVP.Code"
AVPs_List,Vendor_Specific_Application_Id,3,AVP.Vendor_ID,0,AVP.Header,AVP.Code
% regexp {(.*),[0-9]+,} $str1 -> result
1
% puts $result
AVPs_List,Vendor_Specific_Application_Id,3,AVP.Vendor_ID
```

The `.*` is being greedy and matches as many characters, before it matches the last `,[0-9]+,`.

Comment: I also realized the problem regarding '.*' but was unable to bypass somehow. Thanks a lot @Jerry